# Prove that $f$ has a zero in $B(0,1)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

**Suppose $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $\overline{B(0,1)}$, $f(0) = i$, and $|f(z)| > 1$ whenever $|z| = 1$. Prove that $f$ has a zero in $B(0,1)$.**

The below is my proof, but one question, how do we specify that $f$ is a non constant function, as i believe that we need it to be non constant to invoke max/min modulus.

Suppose a contradiction that $f$ has no zero in $B(0,1)$, then by the minimum modulus principle, the minimum of $|f|$ will occur on the boundary of $B(0,1)$ and never the interior. By hypothesis, on $|z| = 1$ the boundary, we have $|f(z)| > 1$, that means that there cannot be a value $z$ in and on $B(0,1)$ such that $|f(z)| = 1$. But since $|f(0)| = 1$, this is a contradiction. Hence the result.

Comment: if f is constant any $f(z)=i$ for all $z$. So trivially f has no zero

Comment: The conditions $f(0) = i$ and $|f(z)| > 1$ for $|z| = 1$ automatically preclude any constant functions.

Comment: @TheoBendit why ?

Comment: @ilovewt   because $|i|=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ has no zero in $B(0,1).$ Because $|f|>1$ on the boundary, $f$ is nonzero on the closed disc. By continuity, $f$ is nonzero on some $B(0,R),R>1.$ Hence $1/f$ is holomorphic on $B(0,R).$ By the maximum modulus theorem, we then have

$$|1/f(0)| = |1/i| = 1 \le \sup_{|z|=1} |1/f| < 1,$$

contradiciton.