# Showing at least there is a zero inside the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to figure out the following problem

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on the closed disk $D=\{z \mid |z|\leq 1\}$ and $M>0$ is a constant. If $|f(z)|>M$ for all $z \in \partial D$ and $|f(0)|<M$. Prove that $f$ has at least one zero in int($D$).

It looks like I should apply the maximum modulus principle: Suppose that $f$ has no zeroes. Then we should consider $1/f$...

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2337956/42969.

Comment: You're nearly there.  What can you say about the values of $|1/f|$ on $\partial D$ and at 0?  What does the maximum modulus principle say about $1/f$? You should get a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose

$f(z) \ne 0, \forall z \in \text{int}(D); \tag 1$

then since

$\vert f(z) \vert > M, \; \forall z \in \partial D, \tag 2$

we see that

$f(z) \ne 0, \forall z \in D; \tag 3$

it follows that $1/f(z)$ is holomorphic on $D$; furthermore, (2) implies

$\left \vert \dfrac{1}{f(z)} \right \vert = \dfrac{1}{\vert f(z) \vert} < M^{-1}, \; \forall z \in \partial D; \tag 4$

also,

$\vert f(0) \vert < M \tag 5$

implies

$\left \vert \dfrac{1}{f(0)} \right \vert = \dfrac{1}{\vert f(0) \vert} > M^{-1}. \tag 6$

Now from the fact that $1/f(z)$ is holomorphic on $D$ we infer, by the maximum modulus principle, that the maximum of $\vert 1/f(z) \vert = 1/\vert f(z) \vert $ occurs on $\partial D$; but this assertion is in direct contradiction to (4) and (6) combined, which show that $\vert 1/f(z) \vert$ is less at every point of $\partial D$ than at the interior point $0$; thus

$\exists z \in \text{int}(D), \; f(z) = 0. \tag 7$